# awk inline command and full script has different output

Tags: bash, awk

I want to count the number of starting space at the beginning of line. My sample text file is following

```
aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
  aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
```

Now when I write a simple script to count, I notice the different between inline command and full script of `awk` ouput.

#### First try

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" | awk '
        {
            FS="[^ ]"
            print length($1)
        }
    '
done < "tmp"
```

The output is

```
4
4
4
4
```

#### Second try

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" | awk -F "[^ ]" '{print length($1)}'
done < "tmp"
```

The output is

```
0
2
4
0
```

I want to write a full script which has inline type output.
Could anyone explain me about this different? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: Try `awk 'BEGIN { FS="[^ ]" } { print length($1) }'` in your first one.

Comment: @Shawn thank you. But how can I change FS later on my script?

Comment: @rowboat The "inline type output" means the output of second try. I just notice that shell loop is slow, so I want to improve by changing pipeline subprocess. Is there any workaround? Should I use perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed your first try:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" | awk '
                   BEGIN {              # you forgot the BEGIN
                       FS="[^ ]"        # gotta set FS before record is read
                   }
                   {
                       print length($1)
                   }' 
  done < file
```

Output now:

```
0
2
4
0
```

And to speed it up, just use awk for it:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="[^ ]"
}
{
    print length($1)
}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following without changing `FS`. Written and tested it in https://ideone.com/N8QcC8

```
awk '{if(match($0,/^ +/)){print RSTART+RLENGTH-1} else{print 0}}' Input_file
```

OR try:

```
awk '{match($0,/^ */); print RLENGTH}' Input_file
```

Output will be:

```
0
2
4
0
```

***Explanation:*** in first solution simply using if and else condition. In if part I am using `match` function of `awk` and giving regex in it to match initial spaces of line in it. Then printing sum of RSTART+RLENGTH-1 to print number of spaces. Why it prints it because `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are default variables of `awk` who gets set when a regex match is found.

On 2nd solution as per rowboat suggestion simply printing RLENGTH which will take care of printing 0 too without using if else condition.

Comment: thanks. It's fine now. But could you add more detail explanation for your script?

Comment: @rowboat, Thank you for letting know I have added that solution too now thank you cheers.

Comment: @quyleanh, please check now a detailed explanation is added let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl. Simply capture the leading spaces in a group and print its length.
"a"=~/a/ is just to reset the regex captures at the end of each line.

```
perl -nle ' /(^\s+)/; print length($1)+0; "a"=~/a/ '  count_space.txt
0
2
4
0
```